# Dot symbol in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, iis, iis-6

When I test my Asp .NET MVC application locally, all seems good and I can open page like this

```
localhost:6911/Home/User/c%40c.cc
```

Then I tried to run it at server(`www.test.com/Home/User/c%40c.cc`) and got `The page cannot be found` exception... I think it's that for dot symbol in my url, because when I had changed username of user from `c@c.cc` to `cccc` page opened successfully.

Who know where is the problem? Maybe something needs to change in IIS?

Comment: Which version of IIS? If IIS 7 are you running in classic or integrated pipeline mode?

Comment: did yuo configure a wildcard mapping to have extensionless urls?

Comment: I guess, no... Can you explain it in more details? How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: this question is older